# Amazon RDS: can databases be setup in replicaton mode?

Tags: mysql, database, scalability, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am studying the new Amazon RDS product and it seems it can be scaled only vertically (i.e. put a stronger server).

Did anyone see a possibility to configure multiple instances so that one is master and the other/s is/are replication slaves?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same question asked (and answered) here http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/thread.jspa?threadID=37823

Looks like there are plans for Master-Master HA or similar but that's not the same a replicated scale-out offering.

Comment: Notice they AWS has RDS replication now

Answer (score 3):

According to the FAQ it is possible now, see http://aws.amazon.com/rds/faqs/#86 :

> Q: What types of replication does
>   Amazon RDS support and when should I
>   use each?
>
> Amazon RDS provides two distinct replication options to serve different
>   purposes.
>
> If you are looking to use replication to increase database
>   availability while protecting your
>   latest database updates against
>   unplanned outages, consider running
>   your DB Instance as a Multi-AZ
>   deployment. When you create or modify
>   your DB Instance to run as a Multi-AZ
>   deployment, Amazon RDS will
>   automatically provision and manage a
>   “standby” replica in a different
>   Availability Zone (independent
>   infrastructure in a physically
>   separate location). In the event of
>   planned database maintenance, DB
>   Instance failure, or an Availability
>   Zone failure, Amazon RDS will
>   automatically failover to the standby
>   so that database operations can resume
>   quickly without administrative
>   intervention. Multi-AZ deployments
>   utilize synchronous replication,
>   making database writes concurrently on
>   both the primary and standby so that
>   the standby will be up-to-date in the
>   event a failover occurs. While our
>   technological implementation for
>   Multi-AZ DB Instances maximizes data
>   durability in failure scenarios, it
>   precludes the standby from being
>   accessed directly or used for read
>   operations. The fault tolerance
>   offered by Multi-AZ deployments make
>   them a natural fit for production
>   environments; to learn more about
>   Multi-AZ deployments, please visit
>   this FAQ section.
>
> If you are looking to take advantage of MySQL 5.1’s built-in
>   replication to scale beyond the
>   capacity constraints of a single DB
>   Instance for read-heavy database
>   workloads, Amazon RDS makes it easier
>   with Read Replicas. You can create a
>   Read Replica of a given “source” DB
>   Instance using the AWS Management
>   Console or CreateDBInstanceReadReplica
>   API. Once the Read Replica is created,
>   database updates on the source DB
>   Instance will be propagated to the
>   Read Replica. You can create multiple
>   Read Replicas for a given source DB
>   Instance and distribute your
>   application’s read traffic amongst
>   them. Unlike Multi-AZ deployments,
>   Read Replicas use MySQL 5.1’s built-in
>   replication and are subject to its
>   strengths and limitations. In
>   particular, updates are applied to
>   your Read Replica(s) after they occur
>   on the source DB Instance
>   (“asynchronous” replication), and
>   replication lag can vary
>   significantly. This means recent
>   database updates made to a standard
>   (non Multi-AZ) source DB Instance may
>   not be present on associated Read
>   Replicas in the event of an unplanned
>   outage on the source DB Instance. As
>   such, Read Replicas do not offer the
>   same data durability benefits as
>   Multi-AZ deployments. While Read
>   Replicas can provide some read
>   availability benefits, they and are
>   not designed to improve write
>   availability.
>
> With Amazon RDS, you can use Multi-AZ deployments and Read Replicas
>   in conjunction to enjoy the
>   complementary benefits of each. You
>   can simply specify that a given
>   Multi-AZ deployment is the source DB
>   Instance for your Read Replica(s).
>   That way you gain both the data
>   durability and availability benefits
>   of Multi-AZ deployments and the read
>   scaling benefits of Read Replicas.

Comment: But you cannot make an off-site (Non AWS RDS instance) read-replica for offsite backup (or otherwise).  Big negative issue if you need a DR plan that includes Amazon blowing up.